# There is a empty line at the top of HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am making something with google map api including the markclusterer js library.

I did not input the blank line in the code, but it appears on the `<body>`. Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot]

It appears in every browser, not only Chrome in the screen shot.

Here is my code. It's written in php:

```
<?
/*
Template Name: map
*/
require_once("map/util.php");
require_once("map/config.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="ko">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
            #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <link href="../wp-content/themes/att-lefty/map/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        //SOME FUNCTIONS ARE DEFINED IN THIS AREA WITH JS + PHP.

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap" style="height:100%;">
            <div id="map-canvas"/></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please give me an advice.
Thanks.

Comment: The DOM as shown in that screenshot looks different from what you posted here.

Comment: The problem may be inside one of your CSS files. Look for a margin and/or padding "top" inside one of your elements. Or it could be a line break. A blank `div` or `p` element will also cause that. Also, what `mplungjan` mentioned makes sense as well.

Comment: But you have a possible amount of white space before your doctype

Comment: @mplungjan Empty line appears same after editing excluding empty space between ?> and <!DOCTYPE html>, so thus ?><!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: @Pointy No, it is the result of this code.

Comment: please post the output returned by browser->viewsource

Comment: @Analysis the code in the png file has the `<meta>` tags etc. *outside* the `<head>` and *inside* the `<body>`. The code you posted here does not look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why does your div have a closing / in this line?

```
<div id="map-canvas"/></div>
```

it should be

```
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

not sure if it matters, but worth a try